# correct usage of clauses referring to subject and object

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, clauses, subjects, objects

I have a doubt on my construction. Here is my original idea. i have written it in 2 sentences.

> Outer bounds are fixed using method A. Method A leads to a closed
>   polygon having preserved their symmetries.

if i combine them,

> Outer bounds are fixed using method A *which* leads to a closed polygon
>   having preserved their symmetries.

**My first question is does this full sentence is correct?**

As far as I know, i think this **Which** refers to method A, not the Outer bounds. that is to the **object**.

Let me take another example,

> She is my wife. She is sitting on the corner.

So, I think if i combine them, it would be like

> She is my wife who is sitting on the corner.

So i think this **who** refers to the she, i.e. **subject**

So, **my second question is** either subject or object, the clause like which, that can be used just after the first sentence? If I ask it another way, I want to know the **place where I should put which, who or that etc. Does it goes to same place whether it refers subject or object? 
Any rule for that like SUBJECT+OBJECT+WHICH+...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given sentences

> 1. Outer bounds are fixed using **method A**.
> 2. **Method A** leads to a closed polygon having preserved their symmetries.

If they are both separate, and the first has no consequence on the second and vice versa, then your construction using *which* can be considered wrong. A better example of the construction can be

> 1. Method A fixes the outer bounds **or** leads to a closed polygon having preserved their symmetries.
> 2. Method A leads to a closed polygon having preserved their symmetries **or** fixes the outer bounds.

But if the construction of closed polygon is dependent on its outer bounds being fixed then your construction can be considered correct.